# Prevent multiple api calls with rxjs shareReplay

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to prevent multiple api calls to certain routes.
I keep hearing that I should use `shareReplay()` to prevent multiple api calls especially when you are going between pages and coming back to the same page. I've used `shareReplay()` but when I look at the network tab it keeps on making the network request. Any ideas? I've made a stackblitz link here = https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jadosn

Here is my `http.services` code:

```
getWaterPokemon(): Observable<Filter[]> {
        return this.http.get<Filter[]>(`${this.getApi()}/type/5`, { responseType: 'json' }).pipe(
            map((clients: any) => clients.pokemon.map((client: any) => client.pokemon)),
            shareReplay()
          );
    }
```

And here is my `water.component` code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.waterPokemon$ = this.httpService.getWaterPokemon().pipe(
      shareReplay()
    );
  }
```

Everytime you enter the Water Pokemon page you'll see the Network request happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how the observables work.

Let me explain (it will be long but useful).

An observable is either of two types: HOT, or COLD.

A HOT observable is an observable that emits a value continuously without getting closed. Think of it like an event listener on an HTML element.

A COLD observable is an observable that gets completed after its first call. Think of it like a Promise.

So, using `http.get` is COLD, whereas using `shareReplay` on an observable makes it HOT

What you are doing here is the following :

- Go to the water page
- Ask the service to fetch data from the API
- Go to another page
- Repeat

With your current code, all the service is doing is returning a HOT observable everytime you call the fetching function (which is useless in this case).

What you want to do is to STORE the result of the fetching, so that you don't have to call the service everytime.

The idea would be

```js
// Service
class FetchService() {
  
  data = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  data$ = this.data.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('url').subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }
}

// Component

class MyComponent {

  data$ = this.service.data$;

  constructor(private service: FetchService) {}
}
```

This way, the service refreshes the data only once, when it is instanciated. BUT, since the service is a singleton (unless made otherwise), its instance lives up even when you change pages (which is not the case for a component, that gets destroyed and re-created whenever you route in/out of it).

Then, the component only has to get the memoized data in your service, preventing your app from making further calls to the API.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I tried following your example but unfortunately I was still getting the multiple api calls when switching between the pages. Would it be cheeky if I asked you to fork my stackblitz? I'm also having problems knowing what to do with my pipe now that subscribe has made an appearance.

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward [here it is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d9b1pf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fhttp.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fwater.component.ts). I only did water pokemons to show you, so pay attention to your http service, and your water pokemon component. To test it, go to water, then fire, then water, then fire, etc

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks so much works great! I was originally following this chap's example but it didn't work = https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-workshop-stream-caching?file=index.ts
If I wanted to cache the data for a certain length of time (say 20000 ms), would I just set a timeout in the services file and clear out waterPokemons$?

Comment: I think you should rather keep the date of the last successful API call and compare it each time the behavior subject is requested, that would be easier and less prone to error, and also could be use a cross multiple user sessions. But I think libraries might exist for that already !